# Loading indicator on the right in an AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I populate my AutoCompleteTextView with data gotten from a web server. Which takes 3-5 seconds. If its not indicated that its an AutoComplete no one waits. Hence I want to show an indicator like this:

[image]

**I tried this:**

```
private class getAutoCompletes extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private String response;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    //get autocomplete data
    return response;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

autoComplete.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
ArrayAdapter<String> AutoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, autocompletes);
autoComplete.setAdapter(AutoCompleteAdapter);
autoComplete.showDropDown();
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    autoComplete.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
            R.drawable.rotating_drawable, 0);
}
}
```

**R.drawable.rotating_drawable**

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner1"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner2"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner3"
        android:duration="50"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/spinner4"
        android:duration="50"/>

</animation-list>
```

But this didn't work. The right drawable is stationary.

Also is the above image kind of a layout having a search `ImageView`, `AutoCompleteTextView`, `ProgressBar` and a go `Button` all in a **no-borders** kind of background? So, that the `progressbar` looks like its inside the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use progress bars not spinners. Use the graphical view to lay them over your AutoCompleteTextView fields and set their id. I set mine to progressLoading.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressLoading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewId"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewId"
    android:paddingTop="14dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip" />
```

Then in your activity/fragment:

```
final ProgressBar barProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressLoading);
originProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

It is automatically visible so we initially set it to hidden. We then set it to VISIBLE on your addTextChangedListener on the AutoCompleteTextView. Then whenever that tasks completes you set it back to hidden.